# Adjusting the priorities and time slices of processes in Minix, where and how to?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling, minix, thread-priority

I'm trying to change the priorities of processes in Minix. For now I'm thinking about changing the `schedule_process` method under `minix/servers/sched/schedule.c`

Original code looks like this:

```
static int schedule_process(struct schedproc * rmp, unsigned flags){
int err;
int new_prio, new_quantum, new_cpu;

pick_cpu(rmp);

if (flags & SCHEDULE_CHANGE_PRIO)
    new_prio = rmp->priority;
else
    new_prio = -1;

if (flags & SCHEDULE_CHANGE_QUANTUM)
    new_quantum = rmp->time_slice;
else
    new_quantum = -1;

if (flags & SCHEDULE_CHANGE_CPU)
    new_cpu = rmp->cpu;
else
    new_cpu = -1;

if ((err = sys_schedule(rmp->endpoint, new_prio,
    new_quantum, new_cpu)) != OK) {
    printf("PM: An error occurred when trying to schedule %d: %d\n",
    rmp->endpoint, err);
}

return err;
}
```

I'm considering to intervene at where it assigns `new_prio`, `new_quantum` and `new_cpu` values. Would this be a good idea? I mean just adding a line like, `new_prio=4;` would be enough? Also, is there a way to see if a process is a kernel process? I know that 0 priority resembles a kernel process, but do all kernel processes have a priority value 0? If I were to give new priority to a process only if it had a priority value greater than 0, would that mean I'm not going to intervene with any kernel process?

Sorry for the flood of questions, I had too many. Thanks in advance.